# Laravel in docker container - can make migration but cannot migrate

Tags: laravel, docker

So I've searched this a good amount and everyone says either make the db host in .env file equal to mysql or the docker container ip but both have not worked for me?

I'm pretty sure it's a host issue but I do not know at this point?

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:

  web:
    container_name: algm
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: container-build/web/Dockerfile
    environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
    - MYSQL_USER=dbuser
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=654321
    - MYSQL_HOST=db
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www
    depends_on:
    - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
    - "6603:3306"
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=654321
    - MYSQL_USER=dbuser
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=654321
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
    volumes:
    - "mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"
    - ./data/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql

volumes:
  mysql_data: { driver: local }
```

Here's my connections in the .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=654321
```

so I get into my docker bash by the command:

```
sudo docker-compose exec web /bin/bash
```

and there I can make models and migrations but cannot migrate?  I get the error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = dbname and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=dbname", "dbuser", "654321", [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

UPDATE, here's my Dockerfile in case it's needed:

```
#
# Use this dockerfile to run the application.
#
# Start the server using docker-compose:
#
#   docker-compose build
#   docker-compose up
#
# NOTE: In future examples replace {{volume_name}} with your projects desired volume name
#
# You can install dependencies via the container:
#
#   docker-compose run {{volume_name}} composer install
#
# You can manipulate dev mode from the container:
#
#   docker-compose run {{volume_name}} composer development-enable
#   docker-compose run {{volume_name}} composer development-disable
#   docker-compose run {{volume_name}} composer development-status
#
# OR use plain old docker 
#
#   docker build -f Dockerfile-dev -t {{volume_name}} .
#   docker run -it -p "8080:80" -v $PWD:/var/www {{volume_name}}
#
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y vim git zlib1g-dev mariadb-client libzip-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-install zip mysqli pdo_mysql \
 && pecl install xdebug \
 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
 && echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=on' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
 && echo 'xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
 && echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000' >>  /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
 && a2enmod rewrite \
 && sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/public!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf \
 && mv /var/www/html /var/www/public \
 && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer \
  | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
 && echo "AllowEncodedSlashes On" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Comment: Changing to `DB_HOST=db` should work on Laravel .env file. I think you have to run `docker-compose up` to Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tried your config and it's working. You just need to change `DB_HOST=mysql` to your container name `DB_HOST=db`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=654321
```

Then go to your app folder inside the container and run `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear` and then execute migrations.

Comment: Just to clarify, with the last commands you are clearing the cache.

Comment: Just got this.  Great,  let me try this now.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works for  me !